# How can I find the image from blob url in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, path

I input a `photo.jpg` with Input tag on HTML. The function will send a blob URL to the server by ajax. The server had received the URL but it showed that

> no such file or directory, open
> 'blob:http://localhost:3000/xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx

How can the server received the `photo.jpg` and then launch a new function?

Here is my code:

```
<form id="form">
<input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
</form>
<input type="submit" id="submit">
<script>
            submit.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
                const Phone = document.getElementById('Phone');
                const msg = document.getElementById('msg');
                const myFile = document.getElementById('myFile')
                var url = getObjectURL(myFile.files[0])
                data = {
                    Phone:Phone.value,
                    msg:msg.value,
                    url:url
                }
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $.post('/test', {data});
                })
            })
</script>
```

server.js:

```
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
SendMedia(req.body.data['Phone'],req.body.data['msg'],req.body.data['url']);
});

async function SendMedia(number, message, url) {
    console.log(url)
    media = MessageMedia.fromFilePath(url)
}
```

Comment: Blob is an `ArrayBuffer` stored in memory on the client. Send the image binary.

Comment: @AdamAzad How to convert from image to binary?